# Warning: Failed prop type of type 'object', expected string

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

Im building an app using react/redux and I have installed an npm package called 'reactconfirmalert'. This works perfectly, but in my console im getting and error message when im displaying the confirm alert:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXJI0.png

Here is the code that triggers the alert:

```
    import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert';
    import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css';
    import { Sharelink } from '../modal/sharelink';
    import React from 'react';
    export const publisher = (message, link, onConfirm) => {

  confirmAlert({
    title: message,
    message: <Sharelink shareLink={link}/>,
    confirmLabel: 'OK',
    cancelLabel: '',
    onConfirm: onConfirm,
  });
  document.getElementById("react-confirm-alert").classList.add("publisher");
};
```

As you can see, "message" is not a message but a component named "Sharelink" that I have developed and want to be seen with the alert.

I have checked the file where confirmAlert is imported from and it says that "message" is expected to be a string just like the warning says:

```
_createClass(ReactConfirmAlert, null, [{
    key: 'propTypes',
    value: {
      title: _propTypes2['default'].string,
      message: _propTypes2['default'].string,
      confirmLabel: _propTypes2['default'].string,
      cancelLabel: _propTypes2['default'].string,
      onConfirm: _propTypes2['default'].func,
      onCancel: _propTypes2['default'].func,
      children: _propTypes2['default'].node
    },
    enumerable: true
  }, {
    key: 'defaultProps',
    value: {
      title: false,
      message: false,
      childrenElement: function childrenElement() {
        return null;
      },
      confirmLabel: false,
      cancelLabel: false,
      onConfirm: function onConfirm() {
        return null;
      },
      onCancel: function onCancel() {
        return null;
      }
    },
    enumerable: true
  }]);
```

Everything works perfectly, but I don't want the error message to appear in console, how can I fix it without? Is it possible to just silence the warning that appears in console?

Comment: Apparently, react-confirm-alert required a string as a message property, so try to replace `message: <Sharelink shareLink={link}/>` by `message: '<Sharelink shareLink={link}/>'`.

Comment: Proptypes warning should only appears on development build. It won't show up on your production build, so you are fine. But if you are still bothered by it, you can probably ask the maintainer of the package to change the proptypes of that particular prop. Or, fork it and make the changes yourself for you to use.

Comment: That will only display '<Sharelink shareLink={link}/>' to the user. I have tried to write message: '' + <Sharelink shareLink={link}/>, but that did not work either

Comment: Oh so it will disappear during production build @Jackyef ? because then it's no problem